# ImportError: No module named PyMySQL - issues connecting with Anaconda

Tags: python, compatibility, mysql-python, anaconda

so I am new to both programming and Python, but I think I have the issue narrowed down enough to ask a meaningful question.

I am trying to use MySQLdb on my computer. No problem, right? I just enter:

import PyMySQL

PyMySQL.install_as_MySQLdb()

import MySQLdb

At the top of the script.

But here is the problem. I installed Anaconda the other day to try to get access to more stats packages.

As a result, on the command line, "which python" returns:

/Users/vincent/anaconda/bin/python

Based on reading other people's questions and answers, I think the problem is caused by being through Anaconda and not usr/bin/python, but I have no idea if this is correct... I would rather not uninstall Anaconda as I know that is not the right solution.

So, I would like to ask for a very basic list of steps of how fix this if possible.

I am on OSX (10.9) Anaconda is 1.9.1 and I think python is 2.7

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to uninstall anaconda. In your case, Try `pip install PyMySql`. If `which pip` return `/Users/vincent/anaconda/bin/pip`, this should work.